# Getting my Word Processor GUI to Open a File

Tags: java, swing, word-processor

I am trying to make a simple word processor that has an open, save, and delete button. So far I have gotten the save button to work! My open button, on the other hand, will not open a file. Whenever I click the button nothing happens. Please help! Here is the code for my open class:

```
    package Word_Processor.src;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class OpenFile {

public void open(JTextPane text) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("RICH TEXT FORMAT", "rtf", "rtf");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

    int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) text.getDocument();
        RTFEditorKit kit = new RTFEditorKit();
        BufferedInputStream in;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            kit.read(in, doc, 1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Open cancelled!");

    }

}
}
```

Also, here is my Display Class that calls the open class:

```
package Word_Processor.src;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Display extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JTextPane textArea;
private JButton saveButton;
private JComboBox colorCombo;
private JComboBox fontCombo;
private JLabel processorLabel;
private JSlider fontSize;
private JButton openButton;
private JButton deleteButton;

// Create some method objects
SaveContent saveFile = new SaveContent();
ColorManagement colorClass = new ColorManagement();
FontManagement fontClass = new FontManagement();
Main main = new Main();
OpenFile openFile = new OpenFile();

// Create some arrays
String[] colorItems =     { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Black" };
String[] fontItems = { "Monospaced", "Serif", "Sans Serif", "Arial" };

public Display() {
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Font font;
    Color color;

    color = colorClass.getColor();
    font = fontClass.getFont();

    // Construct Components
    textArea = new JTextPane();
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    openButton = new JButton("Open");
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    colorCombo = new JComboBox(colorItems);
    fontCombo = new JComboBox(fontItems);
    processorLabel = new JLabel("Word Processor");
    fontSize = new JSlider(10, 30);

    // Work with slider
    fontSize.setOrientation(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
    fontSize.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    fontSize.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    fontSize.setPaintTicks(true);
    fontSize.setPaintLabels(true);

    // Make the text area look presentable
    textArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    // textArea.setForeground(color);

    // Adjust size and layout
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(817, 473));
    setLayout(null);

    // Add components
    add(textArea);
    add(saveButton);
    add(colorCombo);
    add(fontCombo);
    add(processorLabel);
    add(fontSize);
    add(deleteButton);
    add(openButton);

    // set boundaries
    textArea.setBounds(10, 30, 650, 450);
    saveButton.setBounds(670, 395, 140, 35);
    openButton.setBounds(670, 350, 140, 35);
    deleteButton.setBounds(670, 305, 140, 35);
    colorCombo.setBounds(670, 205, 140, 35);
    fontCombo.setBounds(670, 150, 140, 35);
    processorLabel.setBounds(670, 20, 140, 35);
    fontSize.setBounds(670, 95, 140, 49);

    // add action listeners
    saveButton.addActionListener(this);
    colorCombo.addActionListener(this);
    fontCombo.addActionListener(this);
    deleteButton.addActionListener(this);
    openButton.addActionListener(this);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
        saveFile.save(textArea);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        openFile.open(textArea);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == colorCombo) {
        colorClass.selectColor(colorCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        textArea.setForeground(colorClass.getColor());
    }
    if (e.getSource() == fontCombo) {
        fontClass.selectFont(fontCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(), fontSize.getValue());
        textArea.setFont(fontClass.getFont());
    }

    }

    public JTextPane getText() {
    return textArea;
}
}
```

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Please read @AndrewThompson's link and then fix your original post.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you opening an RTF file and using a HTMLEditorKit to parse it? This is a set-up for failure.

It would seem to me that you should use

1. an RTF editor kit, not one geared towards HTML text, for your purposes.
2. You're ignoring all catch blocks, which you shouldn't. At least print the exception's stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast. The only reason I used the HTML kit is because that's how my save class is set up, and I made the open class based off the save class. I'm very new at this and this is really supposed to be a group project but no one else has really been working on it.

Comment: I changed my post to reflect the RTFEditorKit change. It still will not open a text file. I'm not sure if I did it wrong in the OpenFile class or if I am calling it wrong in the Display class. I am unsure what you mean about ignoring the catch blocks. I'm sorry that I am not knowledgeable on this. I have been researching how to fix it for hours tonight before I came to you guys. I tried using readAllBytes to open the files for me but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with the file chooser. Again, thank you for your help on this.

Comment: @CZink: you have empty catch blocks, e.g, `catch (FooException e) {}`, that completely ignore any exception that comes there way, which is the coding equivalent of driving your car at top speed with your eyes closed. Don't you want to know what caused the error should one occur?? At least print the stacktrace so you'll know: e.g., `catch (FooException e) {e.printStacktrace(); }`. Otherwise you're venturing into both dangerous and foolish coding. Please read on exception handling ASAP so you'll understand just how dangerous your current code is.

Comment: Ok I've added the printstacktrace to the exceptions. Thank you for explaining it to me.